# A festa se-realizou ou a festa realizou?

Tags: gramática

Podemos dizer que "a festa se-realizou" ou "a festa realizou"?

Se os dois são certos quais são as diferenças entre eles?

Comment: o certo é "se realizou", ou "realizou-se", o traço não existe qnd se está no inicio. Eu sugiro algum exemplo de frases. Daí, pode ver com o contexto.

Comment: Em Minas Gerais provavelmente se diz "a festa realizou"... mas mesmo lá, seria uma construção coloquial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No sentido de `acontecer, ocorrer` (*take place*), como o Peixoto já comenta, o verbo é reflexivo, e a partícula `se` é mandatória, com o hífen aparecendo apenas quando ela segue o verbo:

"A festa se realizou." ou "A festa realizou-se."

No entanto, é possível construir exemplos de frases que contém a sequência de palavras `a festa realizou`, por exemplo "a festa realizou o desejo da criança.". Mas, nesse caso, `realizar` não é reflexivo e tem o significado de `concretizar, tornar real`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma interessante de observar esta estrutura é pensando quem é o sujeito e quem é o objeto: alguém organizou uma festa (ela não foi realizada sozinha). Assim, a forma mais direta possível (sujeito + verbo + objeto) de passar tal informação seria dizendo "Mario realizou a festa".

Entretanto, a frase pode parecer um pouco estranha, já que o objetivo é falar da festa e não do Mário, ou qualquer outra pessoa que a tenha organizado/realizado. Nesse sentido, a voz passiva é adotada: "A festa foi realizada." Esta estrutura já está perfeitamente correta no sentido que se quer dar.

Finalmente, no lugar da voz passiva, o verbo "realizar" (no sentido de acontecer, ocorrer) pode ser usado de forma reflexiva (como acima exposto). Neste caso, então, opta-se por uma das duas colocações pronominais válidas no Português: próclise (pronome antes do verbo; sem hífen), "A festa se realizou", ou ênclise (pronome depois do verbo; com hífen), "A festa realizou-se".